# Hibernate 4.3 index annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, indexing, entity

i migrated from hibernate 4.2.x to 4.3.x and now the @Index annotation is deprecated. I used to use

```
@Basic
@Column(length = 2000)
@Index(name = "siteOrigin_idx")
private String siteOrigin;
```

to index the strings. I simply don't get how to enable indexing in hibernate 4.3+.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since Hibernate 4.3 implements JPA 2.1, you're supposed to use [`@Index` annotation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Index.html) from JPA 2.1 now.

Comment: ok i get it now. Indexes can now only be placed in the Table annotation @Table(indexes = { @Index(...) }) Thank you very much :)